# Flutter PWA Indexeddb_shim

Tags: flutter, progressive-web-apps, indexeddb

i have created a pwa and i am trying to save my files with indexeddb_shim. i can work as a desktop. But what I still don't understand well is that when I delete my history/cache on Chrome, my files get lost and my desktop app/pwa starts from zero. Can someone explain why this happens? I want to save my data forever until I delete even when I am offline.

Comment: Yes, the user has control of the data in their browser where your PWA runs. If they clear the cache they will need to start over. You have no way of stopping a user from clearing their browser cache or the data from your PWA/Website. Most regular users will never do this, but you as a developer would do this often while testing and developing your PWA.

Comment: I have also done a lot of research and found no solution, thanks for your answer! @Mathias